# (Minecraft 1.10.2) A single command block that checks the location specified for air? Sends a redstone pulse if air (ie. location is "empty")

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Being fairly new to command blocks in general, I am currently in need of a way to make a SINGLE command block check specified x,y,z coords. for "air", and, if AIR is detected at that coord. then send a redstone pulse to a different set of coordinates. This needs to be a SINGLE command block - no chaining!

This can REPEAT for as long as AIR is detected at that location (ie. as often as the command block is run (every tick?).

Can this be done in a single command block? Can it even be done at all?

For clarity, here is my objective:
   I have created a tree farm, where I ALREADY HAVE a way to "harvest" the fully-grown trees. I have also used a (fairly trivial) set of command blocks to allow a "vanilla" dispenser to "plant" saplings, instead of merely "dropping" them onto the ground. The saplings are planted DIRECTLY IN FRONT of each dispenser(s). Now what I require is a way to "trigger" each dispenser to re-plant a new sapling each time a resulting tree has been harvested. Once the fully-grown tree is cleared, the location is front of each dispenser will have NEITHER a sapling nor a "tree" (wood) block present there, thus, it is "empty", and I need a way to detect this situation, and "fire" a redstone pulse back at the pertinent dispenser!

BTW, I COULD simply re-trigger every dispenser at the SAME TIME using a redstone clock, and, if the spot in front was not "empty" for any specific dispenser, then a normal sapling "toss" would result, (ie. it would NOT get "planted" that time around); I could then absorb and return the sapling back to a "collector" inventory (eg. a chest), which would then re-distribute the un-planted saplings as required. I am simply wondering if a command block could be utilized in this particular way, is all!

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Is a comparator output that is powered if the block is empty acceptable?

Comment: Hey, you know what? Let me give that some thought! I may have just over-complicated this issue! I only want to "trigger" a dispenser if the block directly in FRONT of it is currently EMPTY...it does sound like a comparator just may do the trick!

Comment: Darn, that won't do! I have the various dispensers too close together to be able to "lay out" the required redstone dust and the comparator required! Each dispenser is separated by only a single empty block! So, invariably, one setup for a single dispenser would interfere with the other(s)!

Comment: test for air and invert the signal.. might be the easiest approach

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be in one command block?

Comment: When I asked about the comparator output I was asking about a comparator output from the single command block.  How much room do you have to work with? Is lack of room the reason you want a single command block solution?  A screen shot of your build might help you get an answer.  I was going to suggest using the [testforblock command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#testforblock) to test for air.  A comparator pointing out of this command block would be powered if the tested block is air.

Comment: Sorry, guys - I just got done work...

Comment: Could you show me the line of code for a command block I would use with the comparator? I'll bet I can take it from there! I thought you meant JUST a comparator (no command block, I mean...)! And, yeah, IronAnvil - it's definitely "tight" in my build! I have a screen shot here: http://s1146.photobucket.com/user/ZTagre/media/2018-01-27_12.44.53_zpsjujpicic.png.html?filters[user]=147056244&filters[recent]=1&filters[publicOnly]=1&sort=1&o=0

Comment: In this screenshot, each of the dispensers is "capped" with a "noise muffler" block from the Extra Utilities 2 mod...

Comment: Hello? Is anyone still interested in giving me a hand? I'm sorry, but I had to go to work just shortly after I posted / commented the last time, so.; Anyways, does it not seem obvious how a SINGLE command block that could "check" a specified location, and "pulse", based on the contents (or, lack thereof) at that spot? The pulse could be sent to a specified coord., which would / could be a device that requires a redstone pulse (for example). Basically, a "machine" that "watches" a location in the world for contents, and reports with a "pulse" if (or if not) something is actually there!

Comment: Okay, so I got your point, and understand IronAnvil! You NEED the comparator to generate the redstone pulse, so it's just the command block with: "/testforblock [relative-coord-in-front-of-dispenser] air 0", and then a comparator IN BETWEEN the command block and that same dispenser...in "repeat & always active" mode, whenever the location in front of the dispenser becomes "empty", the pulse will trigger the dispenser (and, in my tree farm build, will plant a sapling!)! That works fabulously! Two blocks, instead of one only - not that bad! I can make that work in my tree farm build! Thanks!

Comment: You should answer your own question unless you want me to answer with that answer.  This way an answer can be accepted so the question is resolved.  You are allowed to answer your own question and accept your own answer.  You can read about it on the help center page: [Can I answer my own question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect x1 y1 z1 air 0 /setblock x2 y2 z2 redstone_block
```

Where point "1" is the block you are testing for air, and "2" is the coordinates of the redstone block to be placed, or output.

Additionally, if you don't want the nearest player to be executed, you could place an armor stand on top of the command block and replace `@p` with `@e[type=armor_stand,r=1]`

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if block X Y Z air run setblock X2 Y2 Z2 redstone_block`